# Get $http options in transorm request function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I have a request transform function in my AngularJS app. Depending on parameters passed to $http I need to perform different actions before request sent. But it seems like request transform function gets only data as an input. Is there a way to accomplish it with Angular and only standard $http ?

Comment: Do you want to intercept and add something to all your $http requests?

Comment: I want to perform an action depending on $http options. But I want to do it before request is performed

Answer (score 0):

Use a **request** interceptor:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    var myHttpInterceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', function($rootScope, $q){
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                // config is an object you passed to $http(config);
                // you are free to modify config or return a new one
                if(config./*your logic*/){
                    // I want to perform an action depending on $http options. But I want to do it before request is performed
                    // + you can return $q.reject('reason') if you want to stop this http request with rejetion
                    // + you can return a promise that resolves with config object. http request will continue when this promise resolves or is rejected
                }

                return config || $q.when(config);
            }
        };
    }];

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(myHttpInterceptor);
}]);
```

For more info search **Interceptors** paragraph at [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)